# Asylo bazel build error "struct has no method 'package_name'"

Tags: bazel

I am trying to build the quick start "hello_world" package. but i am getting the following error in bazel. Can you please help? I am new to bazel.

```
$ bazel run --config=enc-sim //hello_world -- --
ERROR: /home/shankaran/asylo-examples/hello_world/BUILD:51:1: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/shankaran/asylo-examples/hello_world/BUILD", line 51
        enclave_loader(name = "hello_world", srcs = ["hel..."], <3 more arguments>)
 File "/home/shankaran/.cache/bazel/_bazel_shankaran/795757229ebec3834830ec8fb369480e/external/com_google_asylo/asylo/bazel/asylo.bzl", line 303, in enclave_loader
        copy_from_host(target = loader_name, output = loa...)
 File "/home/shankaran/.cache/bazel/_bazel_shankaran/795757229ebec3834830ec8fb369480e/external/com_google_asylo/asylo/bazel/asylo.bzl", line 65, in copy_from_host
        _parse_label(target)
 File "/home/shankaran/.cache/bazel/_bazel_shankaran/795757229ebec3834830ec8fb369480e/external/com_google_asylo/asylo/bazel/asylo.bzl", line 42, in _parse_label
        native.package_name()
struct has no method 'package_name'.
ERROR: no such target '//hello_world:hello_world': target 'hello_world' not declared in package 'hello_world' defined by /home/shankaran/asylo-examples/hello_world/BUILD.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.083s
ERROR: Build failed. Not running target.
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Your version of Bazel is too old. You'll need at least Bazel 0.13.